# Align item center inside the flutter Stack widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create widget like as follows. It is working fine for 2 digits. ( like shown on the image "20" ) but if the number increases the shown label is not centered. It is moved to right side. like shown on the second image. How do I fix this? I have tried in many ways, the way I tried are failed. please see my tried code below.

[image]

[image]

```
    Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: profileImageSize,
              height: profileImageSize,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  image: new NetworkImage("$profileImageUrl"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            (this.countFollowers != null)
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 30.0),
                    child: SpriiFollowerCountLabel(countFollowers),
                  )
                : Container(),
          ],
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack(alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,children: <Widget>[])
```

Comment: seems the image is aligned on the bottom, but not moving beyond as shown on the above image

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 30.0),
    child: SpriiFollowerCountLabel(countFollowers),
)
```

use

```
Container(
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0), 
   child: SpriiFollowerCountLabel(countFollowers),
)
```

but i would recommend to use

```
Container(
        width: profileImageSize,
        height: profileImageSize,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          image: new DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            image: new NetworkImage("$profileImageUrl"),
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SpriiFollowerCountLabel(countFollowers),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: If i use your way the bottom label size is restricted to the image size. so if the number value increased the text goes on the second line

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by using the transform property of container and remove the Stack widget and replace it by column

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: profileImageSize,
          height: profileImageSize,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: new DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: new NetworkImage("$profileImageUrl"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        (this.countFollowers != null)
            ? Container(
                child: SpriiFollowerCountLabel(countFollowers),
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -10.0, 0.0),
              )
            : Container(),
      ],
    );
```